# Unable to build protobuf 2.4.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, protocol-buffers, proto

When I was trying to run `make` command to build protobuf on Ubuntu 20, I faced this error

```
google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc:913:55: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&&’ to lvalue of type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
  913 |       proto_path_.push_back(make_pair<string, string>(virtual_path, disk_path));
      |                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:40,
                 from ./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:41,
                 from ./google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h:41,
                 from google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc:35:
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @RafaelChaves I used a dock image to build it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things spring to mind:

1. You may need to specify a given C++ version e.g. `-std=c++11`
2. It appears you can install multiple versions of gcc on Ubuntu 20 as well: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-on-ubuntu-20-04/
3. If all else fails, you could create a docker image to perform your compilation, base the docker image on an older version of Ubuntu/Debian and/or use an older compiler. Also see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229774/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-gcc

Answer (score 0):

Installing gcc 5.3.1 on Ubuntu 20 allowed me to `make` and `install` protoc 2.4.1.

The Xenial repository still has the older versions of gcc available. To add them do the following:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following lines:

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
```

Install gcc 5

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install g++-5 gcc-5
```

Change default gcc to 5

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 5
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

[This post was really helpful with the gcc 5 installation and provided the steps above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1313032/1694996)

After gcc 5 was installed I was able to compile and install protoc 2.4.1:

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo install
```

I did need to let protoc know where to look for shared libraries

```
sudo ldconfig
```